# Why is the traditional countdown absent in the Ubuntu homepage now?

Tags: release-management, canonical, ubuntu-website

We used to get more excited just seeing how close the next release date is and how game we are to download our latest favorite OS. Is the traditional homepage countdown in ubuntu.com gone for good?

Answer (score 1):

there is a countdown in this website for Ubuntu: http://www.thisisthecountdown.com/

also there is page in Ubuntu website: http://www.ubuntu.com/community/countdown

but I think first one is much more amazing than second one!